# Exclude rows in a SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I try to do a paging function with images, it works well when I do the order by like this:

```
WHERE tblUploadedImages.ImageID NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP (@Exclude) ImageID FROM tblUploadedImages
    ORDER BY tblUploadedImages.Added)
    ORDER BY tblUploadedImages.Added
```

That works. But some images don't get excluded when I show images 11-20 when I order by how many people that likes the images.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetMostLikedImages
    @Exclude INT
AS
    SELECT TOP (10) 
         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) 
          FROM tblLike 
          WHERE tblUploadedImages.ImageID = tblLike.ImageID) AS LikeCount, 
         (SELECT COUNT(ImageID) 
          FROM tblUploadedImages) AS ImageCount,
         tblUploadedImages.ImgUrl,              
         tblUploadedImages.ImageID 
    FROM 
         tblUploadedImages
    WHERE 
         tblUploadedImages.ImageID NOT IN 
             (SELECT TOP (@Exclude) 
                 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) 
                  FROM tblLike 
                  WHERE tblUploadedImages.ImageID = tblLike.ImageID) AS LikeCount
              ORDER BY LikeCount DESC, tblUploadedImages.Added)
    ORDER BY 
         LikeCount DESC, tblUploadedImages.Added
```

Somebody know how I can make it work if I order by `LikeCount` (how many persons that likes the images)

Comment: Why don't you paginate using CTE and ROW_NUMBER() ?

Comment: I thought it would be easier this way...

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I searched and found some sampelcodes. (http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/pagination-using-rownumber) I changed my query using CTE and ROW_NUMBER(). If you write it as an answer I will check it.

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer yourself and thus sharing it with anyone who might stumble across this question and has a similar problem to solve ...

Comment: You should write the answer yourself, and explain what you did based on my comment. That would be more helpful than me just duplicating the comment into an answer, which doesn't really answer anything, just point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/pagination-using-rownumber That solved my problem.